# How to rewrite urls

Tags: url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a site at xyz.com, for some reasons I want to redirect access to www.xyz.com to the url xyz.com. Even if they add 'www', I want to alter the address in their bar to xyz.com. Is there a way?

Comment: use mod rewrite using .htaccess. Btw what you tried till now?

Comment: Did you look through [tag:url-rewriting] or search much (here or in general online)? It shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: To stop someone accessing your site with `www.xyz.com`, then don't register 'www.xyz.com' with a dns.

Comment: @richard he doesn't want to stop access to www.xyz.com, he wants to redirect it to xyz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable mod_rewrite in your web server then use
 .htaccess file in your directory with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/xyz\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```